# Set location of web components in web form for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, cell

I am new to C#. I wonder is it possible to set the location of web components such as buttons and panels in the web form?

I have created a 4 x 4 table in my web form. Is it possible for me to state in my C# codes which button/panel to be assigned to which cell in the table? (I don't to manually assigned them using the drag & drop. I need it to be done with codes.)

For example, I want my "send" button to located at the 2nd row, 3rd cell of the table. Is it possible to do that with C# codes?

In Java, we can set the component's location by using component.setLocation(x,y). But now I want to set the location of the web compoenents (such as button) in the specific cell of the table. Is it possible in C#?

Comment: Can't you just declare button's position using markup?

Comment: @ilyabreev no, I can only use c#. Is there anyway it can be done?

Comment: I think you can dynamically create the table rows and cells and put your button in one of them. It's perfectly explained in this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @user3437460 Why can't you do it in markup? I'm wondering if this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: @mason Actually the reason I wanted to do with pure c# is because I wanted to create something dynamic like the `listview` provided by Visual studio. I just feel that doing it with pure c# rather than html gives me more "control" to produce a dynamic webpage.

Comment: I don't see why you can't accomplish what you want with markup. Regardless, it should be straightforward to do with just C# too, but you need to show an attempt in your question.